# SQL: Missing right parenthesis in nested SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

My code looks like this:

```
...
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM REI_COUNTRY_CURRENCY T_CC
    WHERE T_CC.AS_FROM_DATE =
    (
        SELECT MAX(T2_CC.AS_FROM_DATE)
        FROM REI_COUNTRY_CURRENCY T2_CC
        WHERE T2_CC.COUNTRY_ID = T_CC.COUNTRY_ID
    ) T
) CC
ON C.COUNTRY_ID = CC.COUNTRY_ID
...
```

I can't see why it would say "missing right parenthesis".
All parentheses are paired.

Comment: `) T` <- this alias(?) is strange.

Comment: @Mat could you elaborate?

Comment: Remove that `T`

Comment: Post full query

Comment: @MT0 yup that fixed it. Could you explain why an Alias isn't allowed here?

Comment: An alias is only allowed (needed) for a derived table. A sub-query does not allowe an alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are not necessary/allowed on sub-queries:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM REI_COUNTRY_CURRENCY T_CC
    WHERE T_CC.AS_FROM_DATE =
    (

        SELECT MAX(T2_CC.AS_FROM_DATE)
        FROM REI_COUNTRY_CURRENCY T2_CC
        WHERE T2_CC.COUNTRY_ID = T_CC.COUNTRY_ID
    )                                            -- Remove the T from this line
) CC
ON C.COUNTRY_ID = CC.COUNTRY_ID
```

Or, to get rid of the correlated sub-query:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   (
      SELECT T_CC.*,
             RANK() OVER (
               PARTITION BY Country_ID
               ORDER BY     AS_FROM_DATE DESC
             ) AS rn
      FROM REI_COUNTRY_CURRENCY T_CC
    )
    WHERE rn = 1
) CC
ON C.COUNTRY_ID = CC.COUNTRY_ID
```